# What does Daniel / "din" actually mean?

Tags: onomastics

The name Daniel is often translated as "judged by God" or "God is my judge".

As I understand it, its compents are דִּין (din) to judge / to arbitrate and אֵל ('el) God, right? So what does that actually mean?

A more [extended definition of din](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H1777) seems to be:

to rule; by implication to judge (as umpire); also to strive (as at law):—contend contend execute (judgment) judge minister judgment plead (the cause) at strife strive.

I would love to know if anyone understands more deeply what this sentiment would have meant. Is it anything like the modern phrase "only God can judge me", like a defiant sentiment that you don't fear the judgement of anyone else? Or is it more like a kind of an ultimate submission and trust in God as a judge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question of the meaning of "Daniel" can be found in two places - one on the origin of "Dan" as a name and other in the book of Daniel itself.

**Dan/Din**

> Gen 30:3-6 - So Rachel gave Jacob her servant Bilhah as a wife, and he
> slept with her, and Bilhah conceived and bore him a son. Then Rachel
> said, “God has vindicated me; He has heard my plea and given me a
> son.” So she named him Dan.

From this, we might conclude that one translation of "Daniel" is "God is my vindicator".

**Book of Daniel**

The book of Daniel contains a series of stories (the first six chapters) whose plot is identical each time.

The general plot of each section is as follows:

- Divine Providence (Preparation)
- Pagan imposed crisis, that is, challenge to God’s law or authority
- Response of Righteous
- Divine intervention
- Result/outcome of divine intervention
- Vindication: human vs Divine wisdom judged.  In all cases, God is shown to be the true God and His servants to be correctly representing God
- Outcome: elevation/promotion of righteous

Note the important point here - the "Vindication" on all occasions is BOTH of God and God's servants.  Let us see this vindication in each chapter:

**Chapter 1:** Daniel and three friends judged 10 times better, smarter and wiser and their way of life, derived from divine direction is justified or vindicated.

**Chapter 2:** God of Daniel is praised above all Gods and Daniel promoted to chief adviser to the king

**Chapter 3:** Nebuchadnezzar praises the God of the three worthies as superior to all others and then promotes the three men in the kingdom

**Chapter 4:** Nebuchadnezzar praises God as ruler of all (despite his earlier pride) and Babylon become greater than before - Daniel's status is raised

**Chapter 5:** Daniel is promoted while Belshazzar is executed.  Daniels' divine wisdom is praised and he becomes adviser to the new king.

**Chapter 6:** Darius praises the God of heaven as superior to all other gods and Daniel prospers.

There is a similar vindication pattern in the other prophetic chapters but that is another question.

The book of Daniel appears to be an extended version of the question posed by Elijah at Mt Carmel as recorded in 1 Kings 18:21 -

> Then Elijah approached all the people and said, “How long will you
> waver between two opinions? If the LORD is God, follow Him. But if
> Baal is God, follow him.”

Following the descent of Fire, God is vindicated and they shout (V39):

> When all the people saw this, they fell facedown and said, “The LORD,
> He is God! The LORD, He is God!”

Both the LORD and Elijah were judged and thus vindicated by this incident.

Comment: That is truly awesome.  Thank you so much for this thorough answer, especially Gen 30:3-6, which is clearly Rachel's meaning when deciding to name Daniel that, which was in essence what I most wanted to know.  I am deeply touched and edified by your answer.  It means a tremendous amount to me.

Comment: @danieltalsky - I am honored to be of service.

Answer (score 1):

Let's apply the name of Daniel to the character of Daniel. Daniel is saying to himself, "God is my judge." Does he do it by defiantly opposing earthly authority?

His first test comes at Daniel 1:8

> But Daniel resolved not to defile himself with the royal food and wine, and he asked the chief official for **permission** not to defile himself this way.

Daniel wants to follow God's law faithfully but humbly asks for permission from people who are in charge of him and let him **judge** the result.

Daniel 1:13

> Then compare our appearance with that of the young men who eat the royal food, and treat your servants in accordance with what you see."

God honors their faith and the guard allows Daniel and his friends to follow God's dietary law.

> 15 At the end of the ten days they looked healthier and better nourished than any of the young men who ate the royal food. 16So the guard took away their choice food and the wine they were to drink and gave them vegetables instead.

Vertically, Daniel believes that God is the judge. Horizontally, he allows himself to be judged by his human authority.

He shows the same humble attitude later on in Chapter 6. This time, even the king feels bad about punishing him.

> 16So the king gave the order, and they brought Daniel and threw him into the lions’ den. The king said to Daniel, “**May your God**, whom you serve continually, **rescue you**!”

Daniel subjects himself to earthly authority and accepts its judgment/punishment because he knows that ultimately, God is his judge. Daniel's name shows his character.

Comment: This is wonderful context about the story of the Biblical Daniel that illustrates his Biblical relationship to judgement and I appreciate it deeply.  It doesn't quite answer my question, however, which is, how would people at the time have understood the meaning of דִּיןאֵל.